# android barcode scanner not reading the content of the product.Its just showing the number .

Tags: android

I've implemented android barcode scanner in my project but its just showing the content number but not the name.As I am required to read the name of the barcode when the barcode is scanned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google offers [Barcode Scanning Apis](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html) via Google Play Services 7.8 version which has lot of properties to return about the scanned [Barcode](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode) like rawvalue, displayValue, valueFormat, url, email, phone etc. They also offer [CodeLabs](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#1), [Github Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) for more information.